# Can television cables be run through a downspout?

Tags: code-compliance

Is it against code (Houston, Texas; Harris County) to drop cable wires down a downspout? This is a condo complex, bottom floor unit. The cable company dropped their cable down the downspout of the gutter system.

At the end of the downspout, there is an extension hose that is supposed to lead the water down the hose to the pavement to the drainage system. Since the cable was dropped into the downspout and the cable is supposed to be buried in the ground, a cutout was made to the extension hose that connects to the downspout so the cable can be laid into the ground.

This has caused water to gush out of that connecting point, pool, and seep into the condo unit - wet carpet now every time it rains heavily. The management company insists that the landscapers change the hose and problem solved, but I feel this is a waste of time and money bc it would only repeat. They've been evasive and said they called the cable company but will have to send contractors out but no clue when that will happen.

IMO the cable company FIRST needs to get that cable out and encase the cable separately from the downspout (like they did in another part of the building) and then landscapers can change to an uncompromised extension hose. I'd like some "meat" to back this up as this doesn't seem logical to me to drop anything down the downspout...are there any building codes that state that nothing should be dropped into the downspouts or anything that will hinder or not maxmize the flow of water leading to the drain. I've tried to find on web but haven't found anything firm.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Code doesn't really address low-voltage stuff _or_ downspouts. This is mostly a contractual issue, which is outside our scope. Good luck.

Comment: Although I kinda agree with Isherwood communications systems are covered in article 800 of the code 800.133 states the wires, cables attached to the inside or outside of a building. A gutter is not a approved wire way and there is no way support the free hanging cables inside the downspout with a condo or multi family structure code is normally a bit stricter and although no permit is required this is not A neat and workman like Install. 
I would call an inspector and ask this very question as you have to us. I know our inspectors would probably list the above code references plus some.

Comment: There is a lot of understandable rant in this question, but at the heart it seems to be a very reasonable and answerable question. I think that @EdBeal has hit at the heart of it about how cabling should be attached or in an approved raceway _and_ about who to ask. The inspector _may_ have more weight in getting the cable company out to move faster. Worst case, find a connector in the cable and unscrew it. Everyone on that feeder line will call the cable co screaming that their service is out & that'll get 'em moving faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers! This is a good starting point with the code and opinions. I'm new to all of this, but logic kept my brain itching on this one as to why they would even do this.And lol @FreeMan that will also take our unit's cable down but a good idea too!  Rock on and thank you again! Stay safe!